# NestJs service cannot pass data through proto

Tags: node.js, nestjs, microservices, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am having problem when my proto is declared exactly the same with my data format passed from the NestJS gateway service, but my microservice does not receive the data passsed from the gateway.

Here is `user.proto` in gateway and users service:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package user;

import "commons.proto";

message User {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string email = 3;
  string password = 4;
  bool isVerified = 5;
  string birthday = 6;
  string avatar = 7;
  string phone = 8;
  string biography = 9;
  string createdAt = 10;
  string updatedAt = 11;
}

message UserRole {
  string user_id = 1;
  int32 role_id = 2;
  string role_name = 3;
}

message UserEdge {
  User node = 1;
  string cursor = 2;
}

message CreateUser {
  string name = 1;
  string email = 2;
  string password = 3;
}

message UpdateUser {
  string id = 1;
  User data = 2;
}

message FindUsersPayload {
  repeated UserEdge edges = 1;
  commons.PageInfo pageInfo = 2;
}

message AssignRolePayload {
  string user_id = 1;
  int32 role_id = 2;
}

service UsersService {
  rpc find (commons.Query) returns (FindUsersPayload) {}
  rpc findById (commons.Id) returns (User) {}
  rpc findOne (commons.Query) returns (User) {}
  rpc count (commons.Query) returns (commons.Count) {}
  rpc create (CreateUser) returns (User) {}
  rpc update (UpdateUser) returns (User) {}
  rpc destroy (commons.Query) returns (commons.Count) {}
  rpc getRole (commons.Id) returns (UserRole) {}
  rpc assignRole (AssignRolePayload) returns (UserRole) {}
}
```

Here is `auth.service.ts` in gateway:

```
import { Inject, Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import {
  LoginUserInput,
  ROLES,
  User,
  UserRole,
} from '../common/common.interface';
import { SignupUserInput } from '../common/common.interface';
import { ClientGrpcProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { IUsersService } from '../users/users.interface';
import { PasswordUtils } from '../utils/password.utils';
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject('UsersServiceClient')
    private readonly usersServiceClient: ClientGrpcProxy,
    private readonly passwordUtils: PasswordUtils,
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  private usersService: IUsersService;

  onModuleInit(): void {
    this.usersService =
      this.usersServiceClient.getService<IUsersService>('UsersService');
  }

  async register(data: SignupUserInput): Promise<any> {
    const { count } = await lastValueFrom(
      this.usersService.count({
        where: JSON.stringify({ email: data.email }),
      }),
    );

    if (count >= 1) throw new Error('Email taken');

    const user: User = await lastValueFrom(
      this.usersService.create({
        ...data,
        password: await this.passwordUtils.hash(data.password),
      }),
    );

    const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));

    const userRole: UserRole = await lastValueFrom(
      this.usersService.assignRole({
        user_id: user['id'],
        role_id: ROLES.STUDENT,
      }),
    );

    delete result.password;
    result.role = userRole;

    return result;
  }
```

Here is `users.controller.ts` in users-service:

```
import Aigle from 'aigle';

import { Controller, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GrpcMethod } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { isEmpty, isNil } from 'lodash';

import { ICount, IQuery } from '../common/common.interface';
import { IUsersService } from './users.interface';
import { IFindPayload } from '../common/cursor-pagination.interface';

import { User } from './models/users.model';
import {
  AssignRoleDto,
  UserCreateDto,
  UserDto,
  UserRoleDto,
} from './users.dto';
import { UserRole } from './models/user-roles.model';

const { map } = Aigle;

@Controller()
export class UsersController {
  constructor(
    @Inject('UsersService') private readonly service: IUsersService,
  ) {}

  @GrpcMethod('UsersService', 'assignRole')
  async assignRole(data: AssignRoleDto): Promise<UserRoleDto> {
    console.log('assignRole', data);
    return this.service.assignRole(data);
  }
}
```

I tried console.log the data from assignRole controller and this is the output:

```
assignRole {}
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "user_roles" ("user_id","role_id") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING "user_id","role_id";
[Nest] 93952  - 07/29/2023, 11:06:01 AM   ERROR [RpcExceptionsHandler] null value in column "user_id" of relation "user_roles" violates not-null constraint
Error
```

Every other service is working great except for this part. Am I doing any steps wrong?

This is my first time asking on stackoverflow. If I provide any missing context or asking wrong, please ask me or give me some feedback. Thank you.